# Is it possible to solve this sumDouble problem with an if else function?

Tags: java, if-statement, integer

My practice problem is

Given two int values, return their sum. Unless the two values are the same, then return double their sum.

sumDouble(1, 2) → 3
sumDouble(3, 2) → 5
sumDouble(2, 2) → 8

My first thought was to write a if else function, so I wrote

```
public int sumDouble(int a, int b) {
  if (int a == int b){
   return sum (int a * int b);
 } else {
   return sum (int a + int b);
 };
}
```

The thought process behind this was that if int a and int b was equal to each other, then I would return the sum of them multiplied by each other, if not then return the sum of them adding each other.

A problem I am running into is that on line 3, i get an error of ".class"
What does this mean?

Comment: I suggest that you work through a few basic Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic syntax and logic errors. Try this:

```
public int sumDouble(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        return (a + b) * 2;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

btw, it can be done in 1 line:

```
public int sumDouble(int a, int b) {
    return (a == b ? 2 : 1) * (a + b);
}
```

Comment: Does answering this question really benefit SO? As you say, the question contains "basic syntax and logic errors" which are not going to be encountered in this exact form by anyone in the future, so it seems to me that this question and answer provide no ongoing benefit.